# Apple Console equivalent in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, console

Is there an equivalent to Apple's Console in Windows 10?

As an Apple user of many years I've come to use Console to troubleshoot problems and to occasionally see what's going on with the system in general.
I'd like to know what Windows is doing when I see the spinning blue circle attached to the pointer.

Also, occasionally I've seen windows pop up then disappear. Is there any way to see what Windows is doing then?

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: @Josh R apologies for my casual prose...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want Event Viewer (`eventvwr.exe` or `eventvwr.msc`). This will show you all the system logs, and allow you to filter logged events through many criteria. You can launch it a number of ways, but the easiest using a mouse is to right-click the Start button and select it from the menu.

Alternatively, if you want real-time information on what Windows and the software running on it are up to, try Resource Monitor (`resmon.exe`), which gives information on things like what processes are accessing the disk or network, which files they have open, etc. There's also Performance Monitor (`perfmon.exe` or `perfmon.msc`), which can be used to log activity for a period of time.

For additional tools that monitor what Windows is doing, check out [Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), originally a third-party developer but now part of Microsoft. The Sysinternals Suite is generally less focused on user-friendliness, but includes many useful utilities. Some that might interest you are Process Explorer (like a more powerful Task Manager) and Process Monitor (logs process activity).

Comment: Oh, a tip for Windows somebody unfamiliar with Windows: you can just type into the Start menu (or, on Win10, the box next to the Start button), and it will automatically search for you. No need to launch something separate like Spotlight. This is the fastest way to launch programs on Windows. You can search either by program name or by file name.

Comment: Thank you @CBHacking this is what I am looking for. As an aside looks to be, many errors. I'll look in to it and ask a question with that in mind. The machine runs well, as far as I can tell though

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're probably referring to the Event Viewer:

[image]

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then type `eventvwr.msc` + `Enter`

Answer (score -2):

Go to `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management`. Here you will find many useful tools, including `Windows Event Viewer`.

If you don't see `Administrative Tools`, make sure you are viewing *all icons*, not categories.

Comment: I'm not talking about the command line (CLI) as in the terminal.

Comment: I thought that was what was meant at first, but if you search for "apple console" you'll see that it's a completely different piece of software, analogous to Windows' Event Viewer.